# Set position of dynamically created controls

Tags: c#

I created a image control dynamically using codes. I am able to set the height and width of this control but I can't seem to control it's position. How can I change the position of this control?

Edit: This is a WPF application, and SI is a Canvas. Basically, there are more than 1 image available at the same time. It's an application that's similar to a image processing application, thus requiring specific positions for the image to appear in. Hope this clears up the confusion.

```
var webimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Class16\\Images\\DSC_0000.jpg"));
            var imageControl = new Image();
            imageControl.Source = webimage;
            imageControl.Width =(XC[3] - XC[0]);
            imageControl.Height = (YC[1] - YC[0]);
            SI.Children.Add(imageControl);
```

Comment: Is this Windows forms or WPF or Silverlight?  What type is `SI`?  What do you want to do with the position of the image?  @AustinSalonen there's a WPF class named `Image` that's a control.  I'm assuming his code compiles, which seems to mean that's what he's using.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx

Comment: @TimS. SI is actually a Canvas that holds another few image controls that isn't dynamic. I just want to position it in a specific area. I can't hardcode it because this specific position changes all the time. And also, this is a WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control it using the same properties you'd use if you had declared the element in the XAML.  If you tell us something specific you're trying to do, and the context (e.g. what type is `SI`, can there be more than one image visible at once), maybe we can help you with the details.

Sometimes the way to set those properties is not intuitively straightforward - e.g. if you need to set a `Canvas.Left`, you need to use code like:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(imageControl, 50);
```